# How to form_alter a specific webform ajax page based on values of the page before?

Tags: webforms

We are building a registration form with multiple pages (in ajax mode), on the first page, we select the number of participants and on the next page we are displaying a custom composite form to collect the details per person (name + email).

In the config of the form element it is exported as `multiple__empty_items`:

```yml
fnc_person_details:
  '#type': site_participants
  '#multiple__empty_items': 2 # <-- this I want to change dynamically
  ...
```

I would like to have Person Count Elements shown on the second page, but are missing the right hook to do so. It looks like this functionality lives somehow in WebformMultiple but I get lost in there.

**Update 1**

We tried to use `site_registration_form_alter`, but it is only called once for the whole form on render - for later pages, it is not called again. Is there a way to hook form_alter into the ajax request?

**Update 1 End**

Anybody has a hint how to achieve this?

`web/modules/custom/site_registration/src/Plugin/WebformElement/ParticipantsElement.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\site_registration\Plugin\WebformElement;

use Drupal\webform\Annotation\WebformElement;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\WebformCompositeBase;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'site_person_count' element.
 * Main logic lies inside the template and the javascrip
 *
 * @WebformElement(
 *   id = "site_participants",
 *   label = @Translation("Participants"),
 *   description = @Translation("Collects name and emails of participants, based on the person count."),
 *   category = @Translation("Site Custom"),
 * )
 *
 * @see \Drupal\webform_example_element\Element\WebformExampleElement
 * @see WebformElementBase
 * @see \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementInterface
 * @see WebformElement
 */
class ParticipantsElement extends WebformCompositeBase {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function formatHtmlItemValue(array $element, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, array $options = []) {
    return $this->formatTextItemValue($element, $webform_submission, $options);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function formatTextItemValue(array $element, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, array $options = []) {
    $value = $this->getValue($element, $webform_submission, $options);

    $lines = [];
    $lines[] = $value['first_name'] . ' ' . $value['last_name'] . ' - ' . $value['email'];
    return $lines;
  }

}
```

`web/modules/custom/site_registration/src/Element/ParticipantsElement.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\site_registration\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Render\Annotation\FormElement;
use Drupal\webform\Element\WebformCompositeBase;

/**
 * @FormElement("site_participants")
 */
class ParticipantsElement extends WebformCompositeBase
{
  public function getInfo() {
    $properties = parent::getInfo();

    $properties['#theme'] = 'input__site_participants';
    return $properties;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getCompositeElements(array $element) {
    $elements = [];
    $elements['first_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('First name')
    ];
    $elements['last_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Last name')
    ];
    $elements['email'] = [
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => t('Email')
    ];

    return $elements;
  }

}
```

`web/modules/custom/site_registration/site_registration.module`

```php
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

function site_registration_theme() {

  // allowing this module to define the templates

  return [
    'input__site_participants' => [
      'render element' => 'element',
    ]
  ];
}


function template_preprocess_input__site_participants(array &$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  $variables['count'] = $element['#parents'][count($element['#parents']) - 2] + 1;

  // Copy all accessible element children to content.
  foreach (Element::children($element) as $key) {
    if (!isset($element[$key]['#access']) || $element[$key]['#access']) {
      $variables['content'][$key] = $element[$key];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, one solution could be, to copy the whole custom block client side and just increment the index of the formfields by 1 - hacky. I hope a real solution comes around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, which appears to be solid. As written in my question, `HOOK_form_alter` was for some not obvious reason not called in the ajax requests, but during my research I found the [hook_event_dispatcher module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher) which offers a object oriented subscriber based approach to the HOOK callbacks (finally!).

I made it work with this Event Subscriber.

`web/modules/custom/site_registration/src/Subscriber/FormEventSubscriber.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\site_registration\Subscriber;

use Drupal\core_event_dispatcher\Event\Form\FormAlterEvent;
use Drupal\core_event_dispatcher\FormHookEvents;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class FormEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

  public function alterForm(FormAlterEvent $event): void {

    // dump($event->getFormId());

    $form = &$event->getForm();

    if ($form['#webform_id'] ?? false) {

      /** @var Webform $webform */
      $webform = Webform::load($form['#webform_id']);

      if ($webform && in_array('Anmeldung', $webform->get('categories'), true)) {
        $formState = $event->getFormState();

        $personCount = (int) ($formState->getValues()['fnc_person_count'] ?? 1);

        $form['elements']['teilnehmer']['fnc_person_details']['#empty_items'] = $personCount;

        $oldDefaultValue = $form['elements']['teilnehmer']['fnc_person_details']['#default_value'];
        $newDefaultValue = [];

        if (!is_array($oldDefaultValue)) {
          $oldDefaultValue = [];
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $personCount; $i++) {
          $newDefaultValue[$i] = array_key_exists($i, $oldDefaultValue) ? $oldDefaultValue[$i] : [];
        }

        $form['elements']['teilnehmer']['fnc_person_details']['#default_value'] = $newDefaultValue;
      }
    }
  }


  public static function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
    return [
      FormHookEvents::FORM_ALTER => 'alterForm'
    ];
  }
}
```

and for the sake of completeness, as none of this is obvious:

`web/modules/custom/site_registration/site_registration.services.yml`:

```yml
services:
  site_registration.form_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\site_registration\Subscriber\FormEventSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Additionally I configured the number of empty items in the form element to 0, as it adds the number always to the preset fields (which is not what you want in this scenario).

I hope it helps somebody lost in all of this form callbacks and whatnot one day too.